# Using get() to call input objects indirectly within Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I have `n` number of sliderInput objects in my Shiny app, each with an ID given by `df$category[n]`. These sliderInput objects have starting values given by df$value[n]. I would like to define a new reactive data frame where the values are given by the slider values. The code below works for the case when you call the sliderInput objects explicitly.

**How to I call the sliderInput objects indirectly?**

```
df <- data.frame(category = c("Coffee", "Grinder", "Machine"),
                 unitcost = c(1, 3, 8),
                 value = round(runif(3, min = 0, max = 50)))

ui <- ...
         sliderInput(df$category[1], paste(df$category[1]), 
                     value = df$value[1],
                     min = 0,
                     max = maximum),
         sliderInput(df$category[2], paste(df$category[2]), 
                     value = df$value[2],
                     min = 0,
                     max = maximum),
         sliderInput(df$category[3], paste(df$category[3]), 
                     value = df$value[3],
                     min = 0,
                     max = maximum)
   ...

server <- function(input, output) {
   ...
    new_df <- reactive({
    return(as_tibble(df) %>%
    mutate(value = c(input$Coffee, input$Grinder, input$Machine))
    )
  ...
  })
```

The function `get()` should allow me to call objects indirectly but this isn't working for me. I tried the below without success

```
    new_df <- reactive({
    return(as_tibble(df) %>%
    mutate(value = c(get(paste0("input$",df$category[1])),
                     get(paste0("input$",df$category[2])),
                     get(paste0("input$",df$category[3]))
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reactiveValuesToList()` from `shiny`. I would avoid using `get()`, which can be difficult in `shiny` due to the environments created through reactivity and the fact that the server component is its own environment in addition to the global environment. Also, paste isn't needed and because `[` is vectorized you can pass it a list instead of using `c()` and calling it multiple times. You also don't need to explicitly call `return()`, as `reactive()` works just like a function and will return automatically.

```r
server <- function(input, output) {

  new_df <- reactive({
    as_tibble(df) %>%
      mutate(value = reactiveValuesToList(input)[df$category[1:3]])
  })

}
```

You could also just use:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {

  new_df <- reactive({
    as_tibble(df) %>%
             mutate(value = reactiveValuesToList(input)[category])
  })
}
```

This works because you are in the pipe sequence and can obtain the value of `category` without referencing `df`.

**UPDATE**

Here is a complete working example, including a rendering of the table to validate accuracy.

```r
library(magrittr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
df <- data.frame(category = c("Coffee", "Grinder", "Machine"),
                 unitcost = c(1, 3, 8),
                 value = round(runif(3, min = 0, max = 50)))

ui <- fluidPage(sliderInput(df$category[1], paste(df$category[1]), 
            value = df$value[1],
            min = 0,
            max = 1000),
sliderInput(df$category[2], paste(df$category[2]), 
            value = df$value[2],
            min = 0,
            max = 1000),
sliderInput(df$category[3], paste(df$category[3]), 
            value = df$value[3],
            min = 0,
            max = 1000),
tableOutput("table"))

server <- function(input, output) {

  new_df <- reactive({
    as_tibble(df) %>%
             mutate(value = reactiveValuesToList(input)[category])
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({new_df()})
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Indeed, `get("input")[[paste0(category[1])]]` works for the reason you described. However, your code gives the following error. *"default method not implemented for type 'list'"*

Comment: I did not use `get("input")` or `paste0()` in my answer, so if that is giving you an error I cannot speak as to why that would be. Try running my code exactly, and if it is giving you errors try running it from a new R session.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have run the second code block verbatim and I receive the error message *"invalid 'type' (list) of argument"* in place of plotOutput and textOutput objects. For another plotOutput object I receive the error message *"default method not implemented for type 'list'"*. I think there is an issue with presenting the list [category] to the output of reactiveValuesToList.

Comment: For completeness, the first code block has identical errors.

Comment: I have provided an updated answer that lays out the complete working app, including a screenshot of the result. Your OP did not have any mention of `plotOutput()` or `textOutput()`, so we have no way of knowing what is causing those problems. You need to provide a complete reproducible example in your question - I have no way of knowing what is causing errors in code that you did not post.

Comment: Excellent answer, simple and generalised so very useful to others too. Thanks! I'm having some strange problems with my app but your example works, so I'm happy to continue debugging knowing that at least this problem is solved.

Comment: This is too strange not to share. If you add `actionButton("default", "Reset all", icon = icon("history")),
                actionButton("bla", label = NULL, icon = icon("arrows-alt-h"))` below `tableOutput("table"),` all the values in the table below are thrown off. Does this mean I should submit a bug to the Shiny devs?

Comment: @RDavey only seeing a small sample of the app and not having the full code including the buttons isn’t enough of an example to know what’s causing that, but my guess is that there’s something else going on. I’ve used plenty of buttons and reactives without issue, so my guess is it’s related to something in your app specifically.

Answer (score 1):

`get()` will return the one object named "input$Coffee" (for example) that can be found in the current environment, not the value of the input structure with id such as `input$Coffee`. 
You shall try the following code to replace yours:

```
 new_df <- reactive({
    return(as_tibble(df) %>%
    mutate(value = c(get("input")[[ df$category[1] ]],
                     get("input")[[ df$category[2] ]],
                     get("input")[[ df$category[3] ]]
    )
```

Comment: Very strange, I receive the following error when I put this code in: "object 'input$Coffee' not found"

Comment: Yep, my bad: it appears that with `eval()`, you can't access directly the sublist. See the edit of my answer as soon as I have re-worked it.

Comment: The whole point is about knowing what a function returns to you. You can find this - very precious - information in the `help()` of the function (paragraph `Value`).

Comment: The edited answer gives an error of *"Warning: Error in [.reactivevalues: Single-bracket indexing of reactivevalues object is not allowed."*. Using `get("input")$Coffee` for the first element in the vector does work, however. So all is needed is to find a way to evaluate df$category[1] (= Coffee).

Comment: For that matter, `get("input")[[ "Coffee" ]]` also works. Something is preventing the expression from evaluating df$category[1] prior to the get function.

Comment: `get("input")[[paste0(df$category[1])]]` is hacky but actually works fine. Thanks for all your help. If you edit to include this, or find a more elegant workable solution I will accept as an answer.